# How properly calculate cornerRadius depending on the button frame

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

How to calculate `cornerRadius` property based on frame of the button to create rounded corners.

I do not like to redefine each time corner `cornerRadius` for each button item.

I create extension for the `UIButton`.

```
extension UIButton {

    func setRoundedCorners(){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }

}
```

And i would like to know how too calculate dynamically `cornerRadius` each time i use this function.

The main issue to find function that will calculate .cornerRadius for different button sizes. Example below will show small difference.

Example:

Corner radius is 10:

:[image]

Corner radius is 15:

[image]

Is it possible to find function that will calculate proper value that will give corner radius?

Comment: What kind of button you need give me UI i will give you code ..

Comment: The main idea to get flexible function that will calculate proper corner radius for different buttons based on their frame

Comment: But what kind of shape you want like circular or just rounded corners?

Comment: Yes just rounded corners

Comment: self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/0.5; Set some arbitrary number for division and you will get the corner radios in ratio.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. How do you want to calculate the radius? In your code it is a constant (of 10pt).

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk check out my answer hope it will same that you need.  if this helpful for you then give vote and approve it .thank you

Comment: Your added images just illustrate that you want different radiuses for different button sizes. But how should the radius be derived from the frame? Why is it 10 in the first case and 15 in the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main idea to get flexible function that will calculate proper
>   corner radius for different buttons based on their frame

I think it's up to you what you pass as the arguments:

```
extension UIButton {
    func setRoundedCorners(ratio: Double?) {
        if let r = ratio {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width*r // for specific corner ratio                            
        } else {

            // circle
            // i would put a condition, as width and height differ:
            if(self.frame.size.width == self.frame.size.height) {
                self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2 // for circles
            } else {
                //
            }
        }
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let button = UIButton()
button.setRoundedCorners(ratio: 0.25) // shape with rounded corners
button.setRoundedCorners() // circle
```

Comment: Is it possible to write function that will calculate this ratio based on the frame of the button

Comment: Problem that with function wrongly calculate corner radius.

Comment: If somebody automatically votes down on people's answers, will anybody be willing to answer that question?

Comment: But i do not cast any votes down to this question it is bad practice

Comment: i agree with you @pedrouan

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe It is good for the philosophy of Stack Overflow, to post a comment when voting down, to be clear what should be improved in that post.

Comment: @pedrouan Agreed, and I'm sorry I did not take the time in this case. The main problem is that the question is not clear at all and basically impossible to answer properly. Additionally the code you posted is unclear by itself and I would not pass it in a review. What does your method do? Why does it do two separate things? What should it really do? Why does its name not reflect what it does?

Answer (score 6):

This extension may help you -- it computes and sets the corner radius for a given `UIView` instance based on its `frame` property:

```
extension UIView {
    /**
     Magically computes and sets an ideal corner radius.
     */
    public func magicallySetCornerRadius() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 0.188 * min(frame.width, frame.height)
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Here's how I've used it in a "ViewController.swift" file for three differently sized `UIButtons`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private func addButton(frame: CGRect, backgroundColor: UIColor) {
        let button = UIButton(frame: frame)
        button.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        button.magicallySetCornerRadius()
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addButton(frame: CGRect(x: 40.0, y: 100.0, width: 100.0, height: 300.0), backgroundColor: .blue)
        addButton(frame: CGRect(x: 160.0, y: 180.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0), backgroundColor: .green)
        addButton(frame: CGRect(x: 160.0, y: 300.0, width: 180.0, height: 100.0), backgroundColor: .red)
        addButton(frame: CGRect(x: 40.0, y: 420.0, width: 300.0, height: 150.0), backgroundColor: .yellow)
    }

}
```

... and this is what the result looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Try this code:**

`btn1`, `btn2` and `btnarrival` are `UIButton` instances:

```
 btn1.setCornerRadius()
 btn2.setCornerRadius()
 btnarrival.setCornerRadius()


extension UIButton {
    func setCornerRadius() {
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2.0
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

[image: Did u want button look like this then try this my code..]

Comment: whats problem in my this code . who give me down vote please clarify it .

Comment: In my code if you want to give less cornerRadius then just simply divide 3 so your cornerRadius decrease .. If you agree with me then give vote .

Comment: The code's quality is horrible. Names are against all style rules. The (instance) method does not actually touch the instance but a passed argument. The argument's type is implicitly unwrapped for no reason. And so on...

Comment: Also, I don't think pushing people to upvote is the right way to get rep on SO.

Comment: Ok thank you for your advice @NikolaiRuhe if you don't mind then please write same function with your style so i get a new style for how to write a good function.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya : Nikolai is talking about, you already created the instance method, but again taking the button as a parameter as the instance.

Comment: When i try to access that extension UIButton my application crash so i pass the parameter as UIButton.

Comment: @Bharath You try my create extension same i created just remove parameter and tell me its working or not in your project .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya : tested with removing the parameter, it did not give any crash for me..

Comment: @Bharath but my task also did not perform thats Button CornerRadius .

Comment: Ya now it's working @Bharath ,Thank You .now my code correct .

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and found myself a very clear and easy solution. As it is an extension to UIView you can not only use it on buttons but several objects.

```
extension UIView{
    func cornerCalculation(r: CGFloat) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/2 * r
    }
}
```

and then just call:

```
button.cornerCalculation(r: 1)
```

r would be any number between 0 (sharp edges) and 1 (completley rounded edges)